# How to read kaggle zip file dataset in the databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I want to read the zip file dataset from the kaggle but I am unable to read that dataset:

```
import urllib 
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.kaggle.com/himanshupoddar/zomato-bangalore-restaurants/downloads/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip", "/tmp/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip")
```

then I run shell scripting to extracting the file:

```
%sh
unzip /tmp/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip
tail -n +2 zomato-bangalore-restaurants.csv > temp.csv
rm zomato-bangalore-restaurants.csv
```

Then I got an error:

```
Archive:  /tmp/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip or
        /tmp/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/zomato-bangalore-restaurants.zip.ZIP, period.
tail: cannot open 'zomato-bangalore-restaurants.csv' for reading: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'zomato-bangalore-restaurants.csv': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Attempt to download a file from Kaggle is blocked because you are not logged in yet.

Here is the script to download all the competition data sets.

```
from requests import get, post
from os import mkdir, remove
from os.path import exists
from shutil import rmtree
import zipfile

def purge_all_downloads(db_full_path):
  # Removes all the downloaded datasets
  if exists(db_full_path): rmtree(db_full_path)

def datasets_are_available_locally(db_full_path, datasets):
  # Returns True only if all the competition datasets are available locally in Databricks CE
  if not exists(db_full_path): return False
  for df in datasets:
    # Assumes all the datasets end with '.csv' extention
    if not exists(db_full_path + df + '.csv'): return False
  return True

def remove_zip_files(db_full_path, datasets):
  for df in datasets:
    remove(db_full_path + df + '.csv.zip')

def unzip(db_full_path, datasets):
  for df in datasets:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(db_full_path + df + '.csv.zip', 'r') as zf:
      zf.extractall(db_full_path)
  remove_zip_files(db_full_path, datasets)

def download_datasets(competition, db_full_path, datasets, username, password):
  # Downloads the competition datasets if not availible locally  
  if datasets_are_available_locally(db_full_path, datasets):
    print 'All the competition datasets have been downloaded, extraced and are ready for you !'
    return

  purge_all_downloads(db_full_path)
  mkdir(db_full_path)
  kaggle_info = {'UserName': username, 'Password': password}

  for df in datasets:
    url = (
      'https://www.kaggle.com/account/login?ReturnUrl=' +
      '/c/' + competition + '/download/'+ df + '.csv.zip'
    )
    request = post(url, data=kaggle_info, stream=True)

    # write data to local file
    with open(db_full_path + df + '.csv.zip', "w") as f:
      for chunk in request.iter_content(chunk_size = 512 * 1024):
        if chunk: f.write(chunk)

  # extract competition data 
  unzip(db_full_path, datasets)
  print('done !')
```

For more details, refer "[Download the competition data sets directly](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1916075712509993/4305734151232919/2292250781868332/latest.html)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this gives me an error: 
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file    Any ideas how to fix that? @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT